# In WordPress why does my site look like like this when I import a demo?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm a beginner in WordPress. I installed the OceanWP theme then imported a demo for it.

This is what the website is supposed to look like:

[image]

And this is what it looks like after I import the demo and open it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this thing once:

1. Go to Wp-admin
2. Go to Settings > Permalinks
3. Hit "Save changes" at the bottom.

This will do a flush and will make the links work.

If this doesn't work for you let me know.

Comment: I did that. The problem persists. The links already work btw.

Comment: Then which link gives you 404?
Have you tried setting a homepage? 

Wp-admin > Settings > Reading > A static page > "Select home" > Save changed

Comment: Also, I can see that you imported the demo twice. Try doing a fresh installation and importing the demo only once. And before importing demo try to install all the suggested plugins by the theme. It'll help importing demo easily and without any issues.

Comment: "Select Home" worked, now the proper home page opens first. I already tried a fresh install; I uninstalled OceanWP and reinstalled it and then imported the demo, it just added even more buttons to the navigations menus.